# MySQl обрабатывает не весь код

Tags: php, mysql

Есть функция php, в которой switch... если нужно создать новости, то... создаем 2 таблицы и заполняем из содержимым. Проблема в том, что таблицы создаются, но не наполняются информацией. В чем дело?

```
function createModule($Module){
switch($Module){
    //Модуль Новости
    case "news":            
        mysql_query("
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mynewtable_news` (
        `item` VARCHAR( 256 ) NOT NULL,
        `name` VARCHAR( 256 ) NOT NULL,
        `active` BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Активация',
        `necessary` BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Обязательное поле'
        ) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  COMMENT 'Модуль Новости';
        ");
        //Заполняем предыдущую таблицу
        mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO `mynewtable_news` VALUES('id', 'ID', '1', '1' );
        INSERT INTO `mynewtable_news` VALUES('title', 'Название', '1', '1' );
        ");
        //Составляющие новостей
        mysql_query("
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mynewtable_news_components` (
        `component` VARCHAR( 256 ) NOT NULL ,
        `name` VARCHAR( 256 ) NOT NULL ,
        `active` BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Активация'
        ) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  COMMENT 'Составляющие новостей';
        ");
        //Заполняем предыдущую таблицу
        mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO `mynewtable_news_components` VALUES('category', 'Категории', '1');
        INSERT INTO `mynewtable_news_components` VALUES('comments', 'Комментарии', '1');
        ");
        break;
    };
```

};

Answer (score 1):

Не спец в PHP, но по моему, 2 запроса засовывать в один mysql_query( ) - бредово.

В любом случае, нужно всегда проверять выполнился ли запрос без ошибок или нет.
Пример можно найти по ссылке:

[Ссылка на русскую документацию](http://www.php.su/functions/?mysql-query)

Answer (score 0):

А кто сказал, что `mysql_query` умеет выполнять несколько запросов за один раз?

Либо делать это в цикле, либо использовать [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://www.php.net/mysqli_multi_query)

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php

> `mysql_query()` посылает один запрос (посылка нескольких запросов не поддерживается) активной базе данных сервера, на который ссылается переданный дескриптор link_identifier.

Одним запросом можно так:

1:

```
INSERT INTO `mynewtable_news`
    (item, name, active, necessary)
VALUES
    ('id', 'ID', '1', '1' ),
    ('title', 'Название', '1', '1');
```

2:

```
INSERT INTO `mynewtable_news_components`
    (component, name, active)
VALUES
    ('category', 'Категории', '1'),
    ('comments', 'Комментарии', '1');
```

Comment: Да, так можно..  Но вопрос-то был не об этом :-D